# Представить число N в виде слагаемых, где разница между двумя числами между -1 и 1

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, олимпиада

На вход подается число **N** и **К**;

необходимо вывести все возможные сочетания **N** в виде слагаемых, но разница между последующими числами не более единицы;

кол-во слагаемых - **K**;

пример:

```
>> 2 4
-1+0+1+2
0+0+1+1
0+1+0+1
0+1+1+0
1+0+0+1
1+0+1+0
1+1+0+0
2+1+0-1
```

я думал насчет рекурсии, подобной ниже, но не смог реализовать..

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На каждом шаге запускаем ветвления вниз, на месте и вверх от текущего значения.

Как найти начальные значения? Да по формуле суммы арифметической прогрессии

```
N = k * (2*a1 + d * (k-1)) / 2
```

Взяв `d = +1`, найдём минимальный начальный член для возрастающей прогрессии, сумма `k` членов которой может достигнуть `N`. Аналогично для `d = -1`  и убывающей.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/m1myxQ)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void  composition(int n, int k, int last, std::string s) {
    if (k == 0) {
        if (n == 0)
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    composition(n - last + 1, k - 1, last - 1, s + ' ' + std::to_string(last - 1));
    composition(n - last, k - 1, last, s + ' ' + std::to_string(last));
    composition(n - last - 1, k - 1, last + 1, s + ' ' + std::to_string(last + 1));
}

int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    int k = 4;
    for (int l = (2 * n -  k * (k - 1)) / (2 * k); 
             l <= (2 * n + k * (k - 1) + 2 * k - 1) / (2 * k); l++)
        composition(n - l, k - 1, l, std::to_string(l));
}
```

Кроме того, для оптимизации можно проверять аналогичные условия внутри функции `composition`, чтобы не генерировать заведомо тупиковые ветви.